Where or how can I get live or near live network metrics?
I'm just after a metric to tell me the current 'weather' on the network, i.e. what sort of latency I can expect as a Tor Browser user.
metrics.torproject.org provides great historical metrics, but AFAICT nothing like a live or near live measure (e.g. of latency or estimated download time).
I would be willing to try and install and use OnionPerf on my machine if there was no other option, but was hoping the Tor project or someone else may provide an online 'weather' service.

Well, the latency can not be predicted as a metric - due to the nature of Tor and it's implementation of The Onion Routing. metrics website can be even out of sync, not a time back of the real time, it's true - these metrics there are just for a representative selection,not for a reference for sure. OnionPerf looks some way better In My Humble Opinion, so fire it up
